# "NAs introduced by coercion", conversion factor to numbers

Tags: r

Task: sum all elements in the column.

Problem: when doing so, the following error comes up "NAs introduced by coercion".

How do I avoid this? This is what I did so far:

```
load dataset and get the table:
dat <- read.table("http://stat.ethz.ch/Teaching/Datasets/milben.dat")            

get the first column and exclude first element: 
fc<- dat[-1,1]         

transform factors in numbers and compute the sum
sum(as.numeric(levels(fc))[fc]) numbers
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you do `dat <- read.table("http://stat.ethz.ch/Teaching/Datasets/milben.dat", header = TRUE)`, both columns would be integer and there will be no any factors. Think about what you really want and then clarify your question. Right now the code does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, it seems you want to sum the frequency column. The following code (using tidyverse) may help:

```
library(tidyverse)


df <- read_table('http://stat.ethz.ch/Teaching/Datasets/milben.dat')

df %>%
  summarize(
    total = sum(frequency)
  )
```

The output is:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  total
  <dbl>
1   150
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple `data.table` solution. @www comment is best. Then you sum with `sum(fc$n)` and/or `sum(fc$frequency)`.

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

dat <- fread("http://stat.ethz.ch/Teaching/Datasets/milben.dat") %>% 
  .[-1]

dat[, lapply(.SD,
             sum)]
#>     n frequency
#> 1: 28        80
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>